# Task Scheduler using cmd SCHTASK - Is there a way to set the Config for Windows and specify the 'Start In' line?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I work with people even less savvy than me (crazy, I know!) and I stumbled upon SCHTASK recently which is wonderful. This allows me to create a batch file to distribute to them to set up a scheduled task. However, I've gone through the documentation for SCHTASK and I don't see a way to set the Windows version Config or the Start In line.

Issues summarized:

- Currently when I create a task via cmd, it defaults to Windows Vista and I have to manually select Windows 10. **Is there a way to select Windows 10 in cmd with SCHTASK?**
- **Is there a way to specify the Start In (Optional) line in cmd with SCHTASK?** My task won't run without it, so I currently have to manually add it.

Comment: What I usually do is create the task in Task Scheduler first, then export it to an .xml file, and use schtask to import it back into task scheduler with all settings in tact. This way, you can also test the task before export, which is a nice bonus.

Comment: I actually didn't know you could use schtask to import .xml files. That is a really nice bonus!

Comment: Are you working on Vista??

Comment: No I'm not lol. Weird

Comment: I would also suggest to look into the PowerShell commands (run `get-command *scheduledtask*`. They look very overwhelming at first, but they allow you to setup tasks on remotemachines, run them, delete them, set options etc. imo a better version of `schtask`